# Response variable with very high number of class levels in R

Tags: r, classification

I've got a dependent variable in R with about 11,000 class levels. There's ample data for modeling this many classes, however some statistical packages like `h2o` only support up to 1,000 classes or so.

What are the best options for classification models in R with this high number of class levels?

Answer (score 5):

Cluster your *n* response classes into *m* clusters, where `m < 1,000`. With an incoming instance *i* assign it to one of the *m* clusters using your favorite classification algorithm. Once the instance has been assigned to a specific cluster, you just need to run it through a classifier trained on the classes that comprise that particular cluster.

I've used this particular architecture to assign texts to one of n possible "emotions", which I illustrate below. The incoming text was first scored with a binary classifier trained on positive & negative texts. Given the text's probability of being positive (as predicted by the classifier), the text was then routed to either a series of all positive or a series of all negative emotion classifiers where it was a assigned a specific emotion.

[image]

This same sort of design should work your case. First you assign your instance a cluster. Given that assignment, send your instance to the next stage - where the final classification occurs.

Comment: Sorry if this description is murky - its surprisingly hard to describe this - does anybody know if there is a design pattern name for this type of ensemble?

Comment: I have a similar problem I'm working on right now. It's not unlike taking the groups from the first level of a regression tree, then taking the data that fall into those groups, and running a separate model depending on which group it falls into. I'm definitely lacking the vocabulary here. I just want to take the first two turns of Guess Who, not play the whole game ...